# Availability of Frequent LiDAR Data in UK?

Tags: data, lidar, united-kingdom, agriculture

I am looking for LIDAR data of grasslands located all around UK with a spatial resolution of 1m and a frequency of at least once a week.

I've already had a look at the Environmental Agency but their data is far too infrequent.

The aim is to use the acquired data to monitor the biomass of a pasture field over different seasons.

Comment: Depending on budget and purpose it might be worth looking into a UAV with a LiDAR sensor attached. That is of course if you are not looking for historic data and you have a budget - if it is for a research project you may be able to get a grant.

Comment: EA Opendata (LiDAR) is the most extensive for England and Wales, unless you spend a large budget that is going to be your best source of data vs cost.

Answer (score 2):

This data does not exist. The cost of LiDAR collection, storage, and dissemination is extremely high. Even in a best-case scenario you are looking at yearly data for certain cities or forested areas - not a whole country or state.

I would recommend modeling biomass with some other remote sensing technology (Sentinel-2 would be a good option).

Comment: Certainly doesn't exist for all grassland in the UK at weekly time resolution. You *might* find a research project measuring a field or two, but the best place to ask would be your research contacts, not here.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked for data on this [EO company site](http://eos.com/agriculture)? I'm not sure about Lidar but EOS have a platform designed specifically for crop monitoring that allows to make advanced vegetation analysis. They have extensive database for the UK. I managed to build a [grassland-only map](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JEBGC5CwbD14ala11xe-nSqVQTZMPcBt/view?usp=sharing). The platform is not available for public use though, you'll need to contact them first.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".